# Too many tags in "My Tags" results in overlapping UI elements

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

As you can see here:

[image]

I just added [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and now I can't click the (X) button to remove it. I fear if I could somehow get my cursor back into the text box add any more tags, I wouldn't even be able to see them?

Comment: After reading this I added Javascript to my already slightly-overlapped list, and pickled it, as it seemed to lose my first three or four original tags.

Comment: A little more playing and if careful I only lose the first tag. There seems to be a limited amount of space, and the amount of space up to that point seems to dictate how many tags can exist. When the Javascript appeared towards the middle of the box (space to the right) three or four tags disappear. If I don't mess too much, I consistently just lose the first. You man not be able to click the X, but if you get into the box and press END and BACKSPACE the deed can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've pushed a fix for this that fixes the overlapping. Because of the limited space there is a point where that tags begin to overflow the field, but using the arrow key left or right lets you get back to the first tags.