# Custom tab doesn't show questions

Tags: bug, new-nav

I created a custom tab, consisting of the following tags:
`windows-phone-8` `windows-10` `windows-10-mobile` `windows-universal` `win-universal-app` all combined with `any`.

However if I open up the tab, I just see the message "That's a miss"

[image: initial empty list]

Strangely if i set the cursor in the edit field and move it to the start (by pressing the <kbd>Pos 1</kbd> key) the questions are shown as expected:

[image: Questions shown after cursor navigation]

Comment: I think there was something recently which touched on this. Seems the number of tags which can be stored depends on how the tags fit in the box or something.

Comment: However, I now see there is a fix for that, so no direct relationship: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311449/1927206

Comment: Seems if you Save with the cursor having been on the last position, then the search fails. Cursor elsewhere when saving works.

Comment: @BillWoodger Nice, I can confirm that it works with the cursor in the start position while saving the tab.